# How to configure Solr to do partial and prefix word matching

Tags: solr

for example,search:cent point

should be match

1. cent point
2. centrepoint
3. centre points

no need match "point cent".

I try to use NGramFilterFactory in solr6.0,but it always get result that the match order is reversed.
like this:

```
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
```

I try to use PatternReplaceFilterFactory to replace space to  * .But it's didn't work ,only match it as an String.

Comment: What does your tokenizers in the schema look like? It seems like you have solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory enabled on the field that you are looking for and then have the EdgeNgramFilterFactory.

Comment: I haven't use ReversedWildcardFilterFactory . I think StandardTokenizerFactory will match each word and don't care order.But i don't know how to process it

Answer (score 1):

1) cent point

2) centrepoint

3) centre points

To solve 1 and 3, and keep the positions as important, I would recommend to use just phrase queries and edge ngram index time analysis :

- search:"cent point"

```html
<fieldType name="text_autocomplete" class="solr.TextField">
            <analyzer type="index">
                <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                        generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0"
                        catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="20" minGramSize="2"/>
            </analyzer>
            <analyzer type="query">
                <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                        generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0"
                        catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
```

For point 2 it is more difficult as you have a compound token in the index which Solr doesn't know it is composed by 2 words.

You could take a look to this spellchecker[1], it may help

[1] https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/spell-checking.html#SpellChecking-WordBreakSolrSpellChecker

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to match prefixes, you can achieve what you want without using the NGramFilter:

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

.. and then query using a wildcard:

```
field:cent*
```

Since the KeywordTokenizer keeps the input as a single, large token, and you've lowercased it (the lowercase filter also works when doing wildcard searches), you avoid having to index a large number of tokens for each value (which is what the ngramfilter does) when you only care about the prefix of the value.

For your second requirement - the order - where an exact match is boosted higher, query a more plain field definition without the ngram filter - just a whitespace tokenizer and a lowercase filter. You can use the prefix query as your query for the returned documents, then use the other field as your boost query.

Depending on the rule to difference between #2 and #3, you might have to tweak the boost query to get the order you want.

Comment: I use multiple field in qf, so cannot change search string. I try to use PatternReplaceFilterFactory to replace space to  * .But it's didn't work ,only match it as an String.